# Azure DevOps how YAML build path should be defined

Tags: azure-devops

I have defined mysoft-ci.yml file in the repo and committed it in. Now I am trying to create a build pipeline with that file but it looks that I cannot get any path working with that.

[image]

I have tried with same path I use in the build configuration or the path that is in git but none of those work. Am I missing something?

Comment: you just need to write in the path to the file relative to the repo root.

Comment: I thought I tried all possible paths yesterday and it did not work. Today it looks to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem went away on its own. but in general you need to make sure the file exists in the branch you are targeting and supply the path to the file relative to the repo root.